# Finding probability of event counts in a Poisson process with overlapping intervals

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I’m studying the Poisson process and have been given a question that I’m having some trouble with. The question is as follows:

> Let $\{X(t): t\geqslant 0\}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda = 1$. Find the probability that there are two arrivals in $(0,2]$ and three arrivals in $(1,4]$.

My approach was to define the number of arrivals in three non overlapping intervals: $X_1$ for $(0,1]$, $X_2$ for $(1,2]$ and $X_3$ for $(2,4]$. Then, the number of arrivals in $(0,2]$ is $X_1$ + $X_2$, and in $(1,4]$ is $X_2+X_3$. I tried to calculate the required probability as a sum over the join probabilities for each possible value of $X_2$, taking into account the independent Poisson distributions of $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$.

My approach: [current worked solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hLGA.jpg)

However, I’m not completely confident in my solution, and would appreciate any feedback or alternative approaches. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.